# Assign person to defined percentage of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating a distribution tool in order to distribute person to tasks based on the defined percentage for each person. Below is the sample data for the assignee and with their respective distribution percentage which can be found in my "Main Sheet". The assignee can grow as long as the total of the distribution will be 100%.

```
 |---------------------|--------------------------------|
 |      Assignee       |     Distribution Percentage    |
 |---------------------|--------------------------------|
 |          Person1    |         25                     |
 |---------------------|--------------------------------|
 |          Person2    |         30                     |
 |---------------------|--------------------------------|
 |          Person2    |         45                     |
 |---------------------|--------------------------------|
```

In another sheet called "New" I have a list of tasks which needs to be assigned to the person according to its defined percentage. And Sometimes, there is already an assigned person, in this case, to skip assigning to that task.

Below also shows the list of tasks and expected output (person assigned) based on the defined percentage for the distribution. The tasks can also grow:

```
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|      Assignee       |           Tasks                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 1                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 2                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 3                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 4                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person2    |         Task 5                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person2    |         Task 6                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person2    |         Task 7                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person2    |         Task 8                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 9                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 10                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 11                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 12                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 13                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 14                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 15                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
```

In this case, below are the distribution:

> Person1 - 4 Tasks (25%)
>
> Person2 - 4 Tasks (30%)
>
> Person3 - 7 Tasks (45%)

Below is working code that I have. However, it doesn't meet the output I need. And I'm getting stuck on how to proceed:

```
Sub AssignPercentage()

Dim PersonFirstRow As Integer
Dim PersonLastRow As Long
Dim PersonRow As Long


Set mainSheet = Sheets("Main")
Set TodaySheet = Sheets("New")

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long

Dim StartCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim cl As Range

Dim Percentage As Long, i As Long
Dim PersonPercent As Long
Set StartCell = TodaySheet.Range("B2")

PersonFirstRow = 10 'row of F12

PersonLastRow = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

LastRow = TodaySheet.Cells(TodaySheet.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = TodaySheet.Cells(StartCell.Row, TodaySheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = TodaySheet.Range(StartCell, TodaySheet.Cells(LastRow, 2))


For x = PersonFirstRow To PersonLastRow

PersonPercent = mainSheet.Cells(x, "F").Value


Percentage = Round(rng.Rows.Count * PersonPercent / 100, 0)

    For Each cl In rng

        i = i + 1
        If i > Percentage Then
        i = 0
        Exit For

        End If
        
        
        If Trim(cl.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "" Then
        
            cl.Offset(0, -1).Value = mainSheet.Cells(x, "E").Value
        
        End If
        
    Next cl
    
Next x

End Sub
```

The output of the code above is below, which is not correct:

```
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|      Assignee       |           Tasks                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 1                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 2                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 3                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person1    |         Task 4                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 5                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 6                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|          Person3    |         Task 7                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 8                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 9                 |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 10                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 11                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 12                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 13                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 14                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
|                     |         Task 15                |
|---------------------|--------------------------------|
```

Comment: When you say `it doesn't meet the output I need`, what is it that you get?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the current output of the code. It only assigned persons until task seven. Which should be the same on the expected output above.

Comment: The problem seems to be that for the second person the 'For each cl in rng' loop starts at 1 again

Answer (score 0):

If you swap to looping through the task assignments and checking whether enough tasks have been assigned yet, it might be easier to make it work. The below code does the job for me.

```
Dim PersonFirstRow As Integer
Dim PersonLastRow As Long
Dim PersonRow As Long


Set mainsheet = Sheets("Main")
Set todaysheet = Sheets("New")

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long

Dim StartCell As Range, rng As Range

Dim Percentage As Long, i As Long
Dim PersonPercent As Long
Dim TaskRow, AssignedTasks As Long
Set StartCell = todaysheet.Range("B2")

PersonFirstRow = 10 'row of F12

PersonLastRow = mainsheet.Cells(mainsheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

LastRow = todaysheet.Cells(todaysheet.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = todaysheet.Cells(StartCell.Row, todaysheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = todaysheet.Range(StartCell, todaysheet.Cells(LastRow, 2))


For TaskRow = 2 To LastRow

    For PersonRow = 10 To PersonLastRow
        PersonPercent = mainsheet.Cells(PersonRow, "F").Value
        Percentage = Round(rng.Rows.Count * PersonPercent / 100, 0)
        AssignedTasks = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Offset(0, -1), mainsheet.Cells(PersonRow, 5).Value)

        If AssignedTasks + 1 <= Percentage Then
            If Trim(todaysheet.Cells(TaskRow, 1).Value) = "" Then
                todaysheet.Cells(TaskRow, 1).Value = mainsheet.Cells(PersonRow, "E").Value
            End If
        End If

    Next PersonRow

Next TaskRow

End Sub
```